# Does a Vertex Shader VAO need a VBO?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, vao, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying to use a VAO with a vertex shader. This works, but only if I set the length of the bufferData to 0. My understanding is that when using a vertex shader, a VBO is not required because my shader is generating the vertices of a quad. If I attempt to create the VAO without binding a buffer, it will also crash.

As I mentioned, this works, however I am concerned because in Apple's Instruments, the OpenGL Expert reports a severe error:

```
Draw Call Exceeded Array Buffer Bounds
No Buffer Data - DYFKNoBufferData
```

Here is the code for generating the VAO:

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID); // Create our Vertex Array Object
    glBindVertexArray(avoid); // Bind VAO

    GLfloat vertices[12];  // Vertices for our square

    vertices[0] = -0.5; vertices[1] = 0.5; vertices[2] = 0.0; // Top left corner
    vertices[3] = -0.5; vertices[4] = -0.5; vertices[5] = 0.0; // Bottom left corner
    vertices[6] = 0.5; vertices[7] = 0.5; vertices[8] = 0.0; // Top Right corner
    vertices[9] = 0.5; vertices[10] = -0.5; vertices[11] = 0.0; // Bottom right corner

    glGenBuffers(1, &fboTextureVboID); // Create our Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fboTextureVboID); // Bind VBO
    // As long as I set the buffer data length to 0
    // then my glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4) call works
    // otherwise I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // configure vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (...
    glVertexAttribPointer(...
    ...

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Make our Vertex Array Object Inactive
    glBindVertexArray(0); // Make our Vertex Buffer Object Inactive
```

Drawing with:

```
glUseProgram(vertexShaderProgram);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Can I safely ignore Apple's errors? I am trying to use a VAO for the vertex shader because I would like to eliminate all the vertex attribute bindings in my drawing code. Or is there a better way to do this with a shader with or without a VAO?

EDIT:

Here is my vertex shader source:

```
#version 300 es
uniform lowp mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
in lowp vec4 a_position;
in lowp vec2 a_texCoord;
out lowp vec2 v_texCoord;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

And fragment shader source:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
uniform lowp sampler2D uTexture;
in lowp vec2 v_texCoord;
out lowp vec4 fragmentColor;
void main()
{
    fragmentColor = texture( uTexture, v_texCoord );
}
```

Comment: "*so no geometry is actually needed for it to draw*" Um... why is no data needed to draw? Are you going to invent vertex data, by perhaps using `gl_VertexID`? I'm not saying that's wrong, but if the idea is that your vertex shader doesn't need any user-defined inputs, you should *say so* in your question.

Comment: "*Disable our Vertex Array Object*" That's not what that call does. "*Disable our Vertex Buffer Object*" That's also not what *that* call does.

Comment: According to this [post](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182969-Draw-with-fragment-shader-without-vertices) the vertices can just be part of the shader.

Comment: Sorry, I should have wrote *"Make our Vertex Buffer Object **inactive**"* - thats what I meant - I'll edit the post.

Comment: Your updated comments *still* don't describe what those functions actually do.

Comment: Well what do they do then? If I understand correctly, it sets them to nothing (which in turn makes the current ones inactive). I am doing that so I don't possibly change the state of the VAO with other calls.

Comment: Based on some of the content of your question, I get the impression that you don't understand some basic OpenGL concepts. You may want to check out a tutorial to start making sense of how to properly use them.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It is based on tutorials I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick one of two things.

It is perfectly legal to have a VAO that has no attached buffer objects. However, this does not mean "create a buffer object, but don't put anything in it". It means not to attach buffer objects to the VAO. You just call `glGenVertexArrays` to generate the vertex array, and you're *done*.

No calls to `glEnableVertexAttribArrays`. No calls to `glVertexAttribPointer`. If you're not using vertex arrays at all, you should not be making these calls at all.

It is also perfectly legal to have a VAO that contains buffer objects. These work like normal.

What you can't do is create a buffer object that has no allocation, then try to use it for vertex data. That's what happens if you remove just `glBufferData`.

So you have to pick one side of the road or the other. Either your VAO uses one or more buffers, or it doesn't. If it uses a buffer, those buffers have to have storage. If it doesn't, then it won't care.

Comment: You say just use a `glGenVertexArrays` and I am done. The problem is that doesn't work for me. Unless I bind it with glBufferData it crashes on the `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)` call.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock: Are you actually using OpenGL ES 3.0? Are you trying to use input variables in the VS?

Comment: Yes, I am using OpenGL ES 3.0. I am trying to use vertex attribute arrays and uniforms with the vertex shader.

Comment: You say no calls to `glEnableVertexAttribArrays` and `glVertexAttribPointer` but I show that in my code.

Comment: "*but I show that in my code.*" I can see that your code has calls to those functions. My point is that nothing in OpenGL ES 3.0 requires that you set up any attribute arrays in order to render. So those calls are not something you should need.

Comment: I am using them to send texture coordinates and position information to the shader. How do I send attributes to the shader then?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock: Your code is using an empty buffer, so that nothing is actually input to the VS. Your code therefore is not sending "texture coordinates and position information to the shader". So there seems to be a disconnect between what your code is saying and what *you* are saying. You also linked to a forum post talking about how to avoid sending such information to a shader. So you need to clear up what exactly you're trying to do. Do you have actual vertex data to send, or are you trying to manufacture vertex data from within your VS like the forum post you linked to?

Comment: But it is sending texture coordinates and position information to the shader - using attribute arrays (see edit I added shader source). As I understand it I do not have actual vertex data to send, it is being done in the shader like in the page I linked to. In fact, I can call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)` directly before `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)` and it still draws perfectly, and as far as I know, no other vertex data is bound.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock: "*As I understand it I do not have actual vertex data to send, it is being done in the shader like in the page I linked to.*" The linked shader does not take *any* attributes; it has no declared `in` qualified variables. The shader you wrote has attributes, and therefore it must have arrays to provide them. So again, you seem to be confused: do you want to have attributes (in which case, you should have `in`-qualified variables and `glVertexAttribArray` calls), or do you not (in which case, you should have no `in` variables and no `glVertexAttribArray` calls)?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock: "*fact, I can call glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) directly before glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)*" [The only functions that care about what is bound specifically to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` are `glVertexAttribPointer` calls.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) Drawing functions don't care about what buffers are bound to that target; they only care about buffers that are associated with attributes. And that association happens through `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am able to use `glVertexAttribPointer` as shown there instead of `glBufferData`, and it draws fine - but I still get the same warnings in Instruments: *"Draw Call Exceeded Array Buffer Bounds"* and *"Uninitialized Buffer Data"*.